# How to use widget in a widget-less WordPress theme?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

I have a widget-less WordPress theme to which I want to add [Subscribe by Email](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/subscribe-by-email/installation/) functionality.

Unfortunatly the plugin only comes in the form of a widget.

How can I use the widget functionality without widget support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a little bulky for complex widgets, but you can call any widget in any place (no sidebar required) with [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) function.